# How to always push current branch to a specific remote branch?

Tags: git

I've searched and couldn't find an answer for this specific scenario. I want the quickest way to push the current branch to a specific/different remote branch.

Right now the best way to do that is writing:

```
$ git push remotename current-branch-name:remote-branch-name
```

Is there a better way to save something so there's a way to type less, and not have to type out the current branch name?

Answer (score 0):

Set your local branch to have a remote tracking branch of a different name, either during your push or using a `branch` command.  During your push you'd just do:

```
git push -u remotename current-branch-name:remote-branch-name
```

It will than say something like:

```
$ git push -u remotename current-branch-name:remote-branch-name
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@github.com:username/sample.git
 * [new branch]      current-branch-name -> remote-branch-name
Branch test set up to track remote branch remote-branch-name from origin.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
git push -u remote-name branch-name
```

After doing this once, the branch tracks the remote branch. Now all you need to do is

```
git push
```

Or

```
git pull
```

Without needing to specify remotes or branches.